# time complexities on while loop with condition of n*n

Tags: loops, while-loop, big-o

```
i=1;
while(i<n*n)
    i=i+n;
```

> from my lecturer provided answer:
>       Big-O notation was O(n) instead O(n^2) why?

Answer (score 1):

Because after each loop run **n** is added to **i**. So it has to run maximal n times to reach n², thus ending the loop.

O(n^2) would be:

```
i=1;
while(i<n*n)
    i=i+1;
```